# MYSQL Error while creating a function

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `GetSuppliedMedicineQuantity` (FromDate varchar(50),Phid int,Todate varchar(50), MId INT)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN

DECLARE totalmedicinecount INT;
IF(Todate is null)
then
    select totalmedicinecount=sum(Totalquantity+FreeMedQuantity) from suppliedmedicine where  
    DATE(DateOfSupply)>=DATE(FromDate)
    and Pharmacyid=phid and Medicineid=MId
    group by Medicineid;

else
    select totalmedicinecount=sum(Totalquantity+FreeMedQuantity) from suppliedmedicine where  
    DATE(DateOfSupply)<DATE(FromDate) and DATE(dateofsupply)<DATE(Todate)
    and Pharmacyid=phid and Medicineid=MId
    group by Medicineid;
end if;

SET totalmedicinecount=IF(ISNULL(totalmedicinecount),0,totalmedicinecount);

RETURN totalmedicinecount;
END$$
```

While creating the function I am getting an error :

`ERROR 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

I am very new to MYSQL and don't know how to solve this, kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query is doing group by and its more likely to have multiple rows as result set. You may also need to use `INTO` to assign query result to a variable.

Comment: thanks the issue is solved .

Comment: I'm curious in which context you want to use this function